# Write a basic function in R to get the interquartile (Q3-Q1)

Tags: r, function, statistics

I have a question for the code as follows. The question is shown below.

Write a basic function (call it getIQR) that takes in a vector of numbers and returns the interquartile
range (75th percentile - 25th percentile). You can use the quantile function. Remove the name on the
returned vector (i.e. make sure the returned item doesn’t have a name like 75% or something like that).
Allow your function to pass unnamed arguments to the quantile function.

Have your function check if the passed value is numeric and if it is appropriate for this argument (i.e. is a vector or a data frame/tibble with only one column - don’t allow for matrices) - if not, stop the
function and return an appropriate message.

Note: trying to deal with data frames/tibbles of 1 dimension was a bit tricky for me. I first checked
if it was a data frame, if so, I checked if it had only one column. If those were both true I converted
that column to a vector (using [[ or pull). I then checked to see if the value was not numeric or not a
vector.

Here is my partial code and I do not know why it fails to work out.

```
# Write the function
getIQR <- function(vec){
  if(!is.data.frame(vec)){
    stop("This function first requires a data.frame.")
  }
  if(ncol(vec) != 1){
   stop("This function requires only one column.") 
  }
  if(is.data.frame(vec) && ncol(vec) == 1){
    as.numeric(t(vec))
  }
  if(!is.numeric(vec)){
    stop("This function only works for a numeric")
  }

  Q3 <- quantile(vec, .75)
  Q1 <- quantile(vec, .25)
  IQR <- Q3 - Q1
  IQR
}

vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
getIQR(vec)
```

It always says that "This function first requires a data.frame." What else should I input according to the note?

Thanks  so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code

```
if(!is.data.frame(vec)){
  stop("This function first requires a data.frame.")
}
```

is meant to produce an error message if you don't provide an object of type data.frame to your function. It's an input type check.

The object you provide:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

is not a data.frame, but a numeric vector. Therefore you get the error.

So either you decide that your function expects `vec` to be a vector, in that case remove the if clauses and maybe add

```
if(!is.numeric(vec)){
    stop("Input is not a numeric vector")
}
```

to check for it. Or, you or you provide a data.frame to your function

```
vec <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

However, then you need to correct one more error in your function: You forgot to assign the result of

```
as.numeric(t(vec))
```

to any variable (using `<-`), so this code can have no effect